# Certificate Expired on SEDE

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, ssl

It looks like the SSL certificate for data.stackexchange.com just expired.

[image]

If you were in the middle of running queries you would be greeted with:

> Something unexpected went wrong while running your query. Don't worry, blame is already being assigned.

Can you please put [CertBot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to work, to renew those Let's Encrypt certificates?

Comment: [certificate screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orJ8h.png), if anyone is interested. :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm having [the same problem on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCSnS.jpg) and [also on Microsoft Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAO0U.jpg). I can still access it, but that's a big risk and I don't even use SEDE anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. We've gone ahead and fixed the certificate.